# I tested List with remove, result shows "none" what i missing here?

Tags: python

```
def delete_a_list_element(list_data, element_value):
    result = list_data.remove(element_value)
    return(result)

def main():
    result=delete_a_list_element([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `remove()` is inline, you don't need to set it to `result` just return `result` after you removed it in `delete_a_list_element`

Comment: the list `remove` method removes in-place, so the return of that method is in fact `None`. You should return the `list_data` after the call to `remove`. Also, return does not need parentheses.

Comment: So many of these questions recently, wish @Community could dupehammer them

Comment: Its a normal python convention not to return an input parameter that was modified in-place. The caller may end up holding two references to the same thing, and that tends to attract bugs. Your function should return None just like `list.remove`. `None` is a really good hint that the input was modified in-place.

Answer (score 2):

`list.remove()` affects the object in-place rather than returning a new list.

```
>>> mylist=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> mylist.remove(3)
>>> mylist
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Because it does not return a value, the return will always be `None`

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete_a_list_element(list_data, element_value):
    result = list_data.remove(element_value)
    return(list_data)
```

return `list_data` variable. Because currently you return the `list_data.remove()` functions response not the actual list.

So above code will print `[1, 2, 4, 5]`